# How to configure sources.list from the mirror site?

Tags: debian, apt, mirror

**Hello everybody,**

I have just installed Debian 9.8 in VMware for studying and learning this great distro. While installing it, I did not choose any network mirror as I wanted to learn how it is done from command line. Naturally, after installation, I could not update the system or install any software before editing the /etc/sources.list file.

Now comes the problem.

I am a resident of India and I wish to use a mirror site which is geographically closer to me. I found such a mirror site from the mirror list  provided on Debian's official website (mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in). But I don't know how to set proper path of my selected mirror so that updates and software packages could be downloaded from it. I don't know what path I should insert into the /etc/sources.list file to configure the mirror site successfully.

I have already tried inserting the following line -

```
deb http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in stretch main contrib non-free
```

But apparently it doesn't work like that.This throws an error namely -

*'Temporary failure in name resolution!'*

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your `source.list`:

```
deb http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/debian stretch main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/debian stretch main contrib non-free
```

You may also want to add security updates:

```
deb http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/debian-security stretch/updates main non-free contrib
#deb-src http://mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in/debian-security stretch/updates main non-free contrib
```

If you want to include source packages, just uncomment the second line (deb-src).

---

The entries in this file normally follow this format:

```
deb http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1 component2 component3
deb-src http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1 component2 component3
```

For further information about it visit the [Debian Wiki Homepage](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList).